# DOM Manipulations in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

For example I have:

`<div class="btn-wrapper-bt1">
   <button>AAA</button>
</div>`

This button is on the 3rd party element that exists in `node_modules/somebt`

I would like to do some simple class change within Angular environment.

Is there a simple way to change it in `ngOnInit`? Or I need to fork the source and change it within the source?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not use ngClass ?

Comment: Did you try with `::ng-deep` ?

Comment: @DanielHoppeAlvarez can't use the ngClass cause I don't have a reach to the HTML or the code of the element - it's 3rd party component

Comment: @ibenjelloun same - can't reach the component.

Comment: You just use CSS to override the style

Comment: There must be some attributes to accept CSS changes either you can access that element using local variable

Comment: @PardeepJain I need to replace some class in the componet

Comment: To replace the classes you will need to rewrite the component, you can override the existing classes style.

Comment: @IamStalker So are you able your component via local variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the html, add a `#ref` reference to the element containing your 3rd party component

**yourComponent.html**

```
<div #ref >
   <your-3rd-party-component></your-3rd-party-component>
</div>
```

Then, in your component, retrieve the children of the containing element

**yourComponent.ts**

```
import { Component,Renderer2, ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class YourParentComponent  {


  @ViewChild('ref') containerEltRef: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2)
  {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    // retrieves element by class 
    let elt = this.containerEltRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.btn-wrapper-bt1');
    this.renderer.addClass(elt, 'newClass'); //Adds new class to element

  }
}
```

Here is a [stacklblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iwcxuy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Note**: If you just want to change the 3rd party component's appearance, you could just override the class in your own component

**yourComponent.scss**

```
:host ::ng-deep .btn-wrapper-bt1
{
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: it has solved my issue, it's a shame that I need to wrap it from parent container. It would be nice to do it, isolated to self component.

Comment: Yeah I can't think of any other way, unless you don't use renderer and directly attack the DOM (but that's usually not recommended). The demo is working for me (it just adds the `newClass` class to the button container, nothing else)

Comment: such implementation should be wrapped within the component. I can't see the other way. Could you refer me to information on that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference :

```html
<div #myRef class="btn-wrapper-bt1">
   <button>AAA</button>
</div>
```

And in your TS :

```
@ViewChild('myRef') myElement: ElementRef;

myFunc(){
    // do whatever you want with it AFTER you third party module finished its job (that's your call)
    //this.myElement.nativeElement.querySelector()
    //this.myElement.nativeElement.classList.remove('toto')
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to place the reference on the element it's in node_modules